# AngularJS and Ionic moving to next form input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a quiz game, and im using NG repeat to generate the boxes depending on the answer (see screenshot) 
[image]

This is the html that generates the 11 boxes :

```
  <form>
<span ng-repeat="content in answerArr track by $index"><span style="margin-right:10px;"></span><!--this adds space -->

<span class="single-input" ng-repeat="contentt in content track by $index">
          <span ng-if="$index < content.length">
              <span class="box" style="display:inline-block;">
                    <input type="text" class="yo" focus maxlength="1">
               </span>
           </span>

</span>
</span>
</form>
```

Im trying to make is so when you type in a letter, it goes to the next input box. I have added the "focus" directive and created it like this :

```
 .directive('focus', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope,elem,attrs) {

     elem.bind('keydown', function (e) {
        console.log("test");
        var nextElement = elem.closest('.single-input').next();
        if(nextElement.length) nextElement.find('input').focus();
    });
    }
  }
})
```

Doesn't do anything at all, not sure what the problem is - can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: It’s probably because `elem` is the element that has the `focus` directive, which is your `<input>`. Since the input does not have an adjacent sibling following it, `elem.next()` won’t point to any valid element. But calling `focus` on `undefined` should actually throw an error and not “[not] do anything at all”, so I’m not sure if that’s really what’s going on here…

Comment: I edited the question, ive put a class on the input ive tried everything but i cant get it to work, your right though its breaking on the "var nextElement" but even with try catch it wont tell my why

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your HTML structure, it doesn't seems to be another `input` is on next `span`. You need to fist traverse upward to `ng-repeat` element and then again search for input to trigger focus. In this way only you can do this thing.

For that I'd suggest you to add some class to `ng-repeat` `span` like `single-number`

**Markup**

```
<span class="single-input" ng-repeat="contentt in content track by $index">
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('focus', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope,elem,attrs) {

     elem.bind('keydown', function (e) {
        var nextElement = elem.closest('.single-input').next();
        if(nextElement.length) nextElement.find('input'). trigger('focus');
    });
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i understand what your saying, but still doesn't work and no error is thrown either :(

Comment: @pandemic have I applied `single-input` to correct `ng-repeat`, currently I added for inner` ng-repeat.. what it should be?

Comment: should it be something like var nextElement = elem.closest('.single-input span span input').next();

Comment: console.log("test");
        var nextElement = elem.closest('.single-input span').next();
        console.log("test2");

Comment: it doesnt hit test2 so must be breaking on nextElement

Comment: could you create a plunkr please?

Comment: Do you want the souce?

Comment: I need a plunkr, with demonstration of problem

Comment: Problem is  "var nextElement = elem.closest('.single-input')", nextElement is undefined it cant find the input boxes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124161/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-gaz-smith).